# Pandas HDF5 store unicode error on select query

Tags: unicode, pandas, hdf5

I have unicode data as read from this file:

```
Mdt,Doccompra,OrgC,Cen,NumP,Criadopor,Dtcriacao,Fornecedor,P,Fun
400,8751215432,2581,,1,MIGRAÇÃO,01.10.2004,75852214,,TD
400,5464282154,9874,,1,MIGRAÇÃO,01.10.2004,78995411,,FO
```

I have two problems:

1. When I try to query this unicode data I get a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<ipython-input-1-4423dceb2b1d>", line 1, in <module>
       runfile('C:/Users/u5en/Documents/SAP/Programação/Problema HDF.py', wdir='C:/Users/u5en/Documents/SAP/Programação')

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
       execfile(filename, namespace)

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 48, in execfile
       exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

     File "C:/Users/u5en/Documents/SAP/Programação/Problema HDF.py", line 15, in <module>
       store.select("EKKA", "columns=['Mdt', 'Fornecedor']")

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 665, in select
       return it.get_result()

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1359, in get_result
       results = self.func(self.start, self.stop, where)

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 658, in func
       columns=columns, **kwargs)

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3968, in read
       if not self.read_axes(where=where, **kwargs):

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3201, in read_axes
       a.convert(values, nan_rep=self.nan_rep, encoding=self.encoding)

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 2058, in convert
       self.data, nan_rep=nan_rep, encoding=encoding)

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 4359, in _unconvert_string_array
       data = f(data)

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1700, in __call__
       return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1769, in _vectorize_call
       outputs = ufunc(*inputs)

     File "C:\Users\u5en\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 4358, in <lambda>
       f = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.decode(encoding), otypes=[np.object])

   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: unexpected end of data
   ```

How can I *store* and *query* my unicode data in hdf5?

2. I have many tables with column names I do not know beforehand and which are not proper `pytable` names (`NaturalNameWarning`). I would like the user to be able to query on this columns, so I wonder how could I query these when their name prevents me? I see this used to have [no easy fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277059/pandas-hdf5-select-with-where-on-non-natural-named-columns), so if that is still the case I will just remove the offending characters from the heading.

   ```
   import csv
   import pandas as pd
   dados = pd.read_csv("EKKA - Cópia.csv")
   print(dados)
   store= pd.HDFStore('teste.h5' , encoding="utf-8")
   store.append("EKKA", dados, format="table", data_columns=True)
   store.select("EKKA", "columns=['Mdt', 'Fornecedor']")
   store.close()
   ```

Would I be *better off* doing this in `sqlite`?

Environment:

- Windows 7 64bit
- Pandas 15.2
- NumPy 1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

So under Python 2.7 on Windows 7, pandas 0.15.2, everything worked as expected, no encoding necessary. However on Python 3.4, the following worked for me. Apparently some characters are not representable in 'utf-8'; 'latin1' encoding usually solves these issues. Note that I had to read the csv in the first place with this encoding.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('../../test.csv',encoding='latin1')
>>> df
   Mdt   Doccompra  OrgC  Cen  NumP Criadopor   Dtcriacao  Fornecedor   P Fun
0  400  8751215432  2581  NaN     1  MIGRAÇ\xc3O  01.10.2004    75852214 NaN  TD
1  400  5464282154  9874  NaN     1  MIGRAÇ\xc3O  01.10.2004    78995411 NaN  FO
```

Further, the encoding must be specified not when opening the store, but on the `append/put` calls

```
>>> df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',format='table',mode='w',data_columns=True,encoding='latin1')

>>> pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df')
   Mdt   Doccompra  OrgC  Cen  NumP Criadopor   Dtcriacao  Fornecedor   P Fun
0  400  8751215432  2581  NaN     1  MIGRAÇ\xc3O  01.10.2004    75852214 NaN  TD
1  400  5464282154  9874  NaN     1  MIGRAÇ\xc3O  01.10.2004    78995411 NaN  FO
```

Once it is written encoded, it is not necessary to specify the encoding when reading.